# How to take an inputted file and count the letters in each word and print it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text document of 7000 words that I have to go through and count the letters in each word. So I am stuck on trying to break up each line at the '/n' and having it count it. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

```
from string import *

def main():
    fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
    infile = open(fname,'r')
    lines = 0


    for line in infile.readlines():
        lines = lines + 1
        letters = line.split(line)
        x = str(letters)

        print len(x)
        print line


    print lines
main()
```

Comment: Are we to understand that the words are space delimited, and that there are multiple lines?

Comment: yes, there is one word per line.

Comment: in this case your delimiter should be \r or \n, I'm not sure about python, you may have to escape it like  \\\r or \\\n.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to break up the file into lines using a linefeed, Python will do that for you. In your comment you said the file had one word per line, so you could do this:

```
line_count = 0
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1
        print len(line)
        print line

print line_count
```